# dplyr: create new variable based upon grouping

Tags: r, dplyr

Given this dataframe:

```
library(dplyr)
df.ex <- tibble(id = c(rep(1, 4), rep(2, 4), rep(3, 4)),
var1 = c('a','a','b','b','a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b'))
```

I would like to create a new variable `var2` based upon the presence of `b` in `var1` which is grouped by the `id` column. Thus each `id`, can then only contain one type of value in the output column. This is the hoped for outcome:

```
df.ex.outcome <- tibble(id = c(rep(1, 4), rep(2, 4), rep(3, 4)),
            var1 = c('a','a','b','b','a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b'),
            var2 = c(rep('foo', 4), rep('bar', 4), rep('foo', 4)))
```

I thought that using `group_by` would solve this, however it doesn't appear to work, like so:

```
df.ex <- df.ex %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(var2 = if_else(var1 %in% 'b', 'foo','bar'))
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can wrap with `any`

```
df.ex %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(var2 = case_when(any(var1 == "b")~ "foo", TRUE ~ "bar"))
# A tibble: 12 x 3
# Groups:   id [3]
#      id var1  var2 
#   <dbl> <chr> <chr>
# 1     1 a     foo  
# 2     1 a     foo  
# 3     1 b     foo  
# 4     1 b     foo  
# 5     2 a     bar  
# 6     2 a     bar  
# 7     2 a     bar  
# 8     2 a     bar  
# 9     3 b     foo  
#10     3 b     foo  
#11     3 b     foo  
#12     3 b     foo
```

---

Or reverse the arguments for `%in%`

```
df.ex %>% 
   group_by(id) %>% 
   mutate(var2 = case_when("b" %in% var1 ~ "foo", TRUE ~ "bar"))
```

Or using `if_else`

```
df.ex %>% 
      group_by(id) %>% 
      mutate(var2 = if_else('b' %in% var1, 'foo','bar'))
```

so that there will a single TRUE/FALSE output from `%in%`, which we can also use with `if/else`

```
df.ex %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    mutate(var2 = if("b" %in% var1) "foo" else "bar")
```